# Cannot start up-clock up

Tags: ppa, clock

How to start [Up-clock](http://gabrielbarbosanascimento.github.io/Up-Clock/) in Ubuntu 21.04?
I installed it via Terminal and placed it's symbol on Desktop.
Now, how to start it up?
And can it be on a screen continuously, even in "sleep" mode?
Thanks.

Comment: Cannot you open it from the menu? What happens when you enter the command `up-clock` in terminal?

Comment: Terminal answered: <Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/up-clock", line 48, in <module>
    up_clock.main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/up_clock/__init__.py", line 45, in main
    window = UpClockWindow.UpClockWindow()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/up_clock_lib/Window.py", line 47, in __new__
    builder = get_builder('UpClockWindow')>

Comment: Terminal continued: <File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/up_clock_lib/helpers.py", line 43, in get_builder
    builder.add_from_file(ui_filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/up_clock_lib/Builder.py", line 88, in add_from_file
    ele_widgets = tree.getiterator("object")
AttributeError: 'ElementTree' object has no attribute 'getiterator'>

Comment: Main menu  (via Alt-F1) does nothing. Please note, I'm not a computer engineer.

Comment: It worked in Ubuntu 20.04, and I did not know that it does not work in 21.04. The main developer is not anymore active, and now I maintain this project. It may take some time to fix.

*I'm not a computer engineer* -- Don't worry, neither am I. Thanks for reporting the bug.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been [fixed](https://github.com/gabrielbarbosanascimento/Up-Clock/commit/97c4dfffb5d5b7d6ee7cb44bbd4b6f82493a3d18) in the latest version, and available for Ubuntu 18.04+.

The issue came up because `getiterator` was deprecated in Python3.9. It can be fixed by [replacing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64744395/3128341) `tree.getiterator` with `tree.iter` in the source code.

[image]
To install Up Clock run the following commands.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/up-clock
sudo apt install up-clock
```